# Partition for quick sort breaks when the pivot is the minimum

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I'm choosing the middle point as the pivot but I'm not sure that matters.

If the pivot is the minimum value in the set it does not work correctly.

How can I pick a pivot so that I can correctly create a partition for later use in the quick sort algorithm?

```
/*

Modified from:

https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/11/27/computer-science-in-javascript-quicksort/

*/
function partition (arr, i, j) {
  let pivot = Math.floor((i + j) / 2);
  while(i <= j) {
    while(arr[i] < arr[pivot]) { i++; }
    while(arr[j] > arr[pivot]) { j--; }
    if(i <= j) {
      swap(arr, i, j)
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  }
  return i;
}

function swap(list, ind1, ind2) {
  let temp = list[ind1];
  list[ind1] = list[ind2];
  list[ind2] = temp;
}

// pivot is minimum, breaks partition
let arr = [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 4];

// start - [2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 4]
// swap1 - [0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4]

partition(arr, 0, arr.length - 1)
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "breaks partition"?

Comment: The code you posted states "*Modified from https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/11/27/computer-science-in-javascript-quicksort/*". Does one need to read and understand the linked article? Did *you* modify their code, and if so, what did you modify and *why*?

Comment: Are you sure that's the only thing you modified?

Comment: I removed left and right, changed the style, and inadvertently changed the pivot calculation.  But either way the code breaks for when the pivot is the minimum or maximum value.

Comment: Hm, it doesn't when you don't change how the pivot is accessed. What exactly do you mean by "the code breaks"? What happens and what did you expect instead?

Comment: O.K.  I think I see that I handles the case correctly.  I did not understand why it was returning `i` until now but now I do.  It will return `1` for the example above.  This means that below  index 1, values should be less than that pivot and for above index 1 the values should be greater than the pivot.  It seems to work but it was not intuitive.

Comment: It's "less or equal" and "greater or equal" than the pivot, but yes that's the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't keep an *index* for the pivot, keep the pivot element *value* so that you can still compare to it even when it gets swapped around:

```
function partition (arr, i, j) {
  const pivotIndex = Math.floor((i + j) / 2);
  const pivot = arr[pivotIndex];
  while(i <= j) {
    while(arr[i] < pivot) { i++; }
    while(arr[j] > pivot) { j--; }
    if(i <= j) {
      swap(arr, i, j)
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  }
  return i;
}
```

Also you will need to change the `<=` operators into `<`, but that problem has nothing to do with picking the pivot.

Comment: That is exactly functionally equivalent to the code I posted.

Comment: @BrannonTeeer Um, no? What makes you think so? Even for the example that you posted, it does return a different result.

Comment: Can you elaborate ?

Comment: You appear to calculate the pivot value outside the outer while loop, while I calculate it inside the while loop.  It is only calculated once per function call.  I don't see the difference.

Comment: @BrannonTeeer Well yes, you are accessing `arr[pivot]` inside the loop, at a time where the value at that position might already be swapped with something else. `arr[pivot]` will not always evaluate to the same value!

Comment: I'm assuming that <= needs to change to < b.c. if they are equal there is no need to do a swap?  Do you mean in both the `while` and the `if`?

Comment: Yes, in both places - not only is there no need to swap, but I think you also don't want to increment `i` past the "middle" before returning it - i.e. [in this picture from the article](https://www.nczonline.net/images/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/quicksort_partition1.png), at step 7 I'm interested in the yellow position (where the pivot ended up) not in the one where the arrows points to in step 8.

Comment: I did notice that he appears consistent in  both the diagram and the code.  I also noted that `i` in the code ( left arrow in the diagram ) is being returned to the actual quickSort function.  It seems to be internally consistent but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the correct way to do the partition or do you think is correct now?

Comment: They use `<=` in that example ... either way it should not effect Big O.

Comment: @BrannonTeeer Yes, it doesn't affect time complexity, but it does affect the result. If you afterwards use the shifted `i` (the right arrow) correctly then it doesn't matter, but this seems really weird as in the arguments of the function the end is the index of the last element, not as usual the index after the last element.

Comment: The `<=` in the if statement part does not make sense for one certain reason and that is that swapping an item with itself is a wasted operation.

Comment: I did some testing and you can only remove the equal part from the while statement.  Otherwise an infinite loop occurs.  Throw the code in a repl.it to see.